# crt_externs.h on iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode

I've compiled the app for iOS Simulator successfully but i failed to do it for iOS device.

I've found that the file is presented for iOS Simulator, but it's absent for device:

```
$ ls /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/
MacOSX.platform         iPhoneOS.platform       iPhoneSimulator.platform

$ find /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/ -name "crt_externs.h"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms//iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.1.sdk/usr/include/crt_externs.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms//iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk/usr/include/crt_externs.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms//MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/usr/include/crt_externs.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms//MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/include/crt_externs.h
```

What's the reason and how can i workaround it?

Comment: Don't use crt_externs.h for iOS?  I don't think there's anything there that's a public api.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure why Apple didn't include them with the device headers but simply copying them from Simulator to Device folder works fine.

P.S: As far as I remember, this trick is not just to compile the solution. It also works as expected so far ;)

Answer (score 0):

I manually copy the [source](https://opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-320/include/crt_externs.h.auto.html) from internet to get it compiled.